# Confusion with Associativity of Assignment operator in C

Tags: c

As we all know that Associativity of assignment operator is from right to left but 
in the given code output should be zero if we go from right to left but output is 1 .

```
 main()
 {
 int a=3,b=2;
 a=a==b==0;
 printf("%d",a);
 }
```

How output is coming out to be 1 if we go by right to letf??

If we go by right to left then (b==0) should be Evaluated first and gives result 0 and then expression (a==0) is Evaluated also gives 0 and at last a's value will be 0.

Comment: Understanding the assignment operator doesn't save you if you don't also understand the comparison operator that you're using in the same statement.

Comment: Thanks Kerrek i got your point

Comment: a == b == c is the same as (a == b) == c ...

Comment: This is not related to Xcode. Any standards-conformant C compiler within any reasonable IDE (and without any IDE at all) would produce the same (correct) result. Also, no, it isn't, but read the Wikipedia article on C operators.

Comment: H2CO3, if it's undefined, the compiler can do anything it wants.

Comment: @DanWesnor Objective C is a strict superset of C. Since there is no official objective C specification you can check the C specification that explains in section 6.5.9 that the equality expression returns a type `int` and clearly states: "the operators yields 1 if the speciﬁed relation is true and 0 if it is false", if you read the spec it also [explains why a<b<c doesn't work](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) and how it evaluates.

Comment: What @H2CO3 was trying to say is that it's _not_ undefined so the compiler _can't_ do anything it wants. It's evaluated as an `(equality_expression == equality_expression) == equality_expression` as states in section 6.5.9 in the specification, (and 6.5.8 for the relational_expression which forms the left part). I think my answer shows a simple counter example.

Comment: @DanWesnor [I've opened the fact you felt people were assuming you're stupid to discussion. I'd love to hear your comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187796/i-think-i-have-offended-a-user-how-did-this-happen-and-what-do-i-do-now?noredirect=1#comment577712_187796)

Comment: "Is this behavior defined or undefined?" Anyone who wrote a C compiler should know the answer to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assignment is done RTL, but equality (`==`) isn't.

The statement is actually:

```
a = ((a == b) == 0)
```

The right hand side of the assignment is evaluated from left to right. In steps, this is what's happening:

1. `a == b` is `0`
2. `0 == 0` is `1`
3. `1` is assigned to `a`

Comment: I think it has do with the Associativity of comparison operator rather other way around.

Comment: @Amit: The *comparison* operator goes from left to right! For a good example of an *assignment* operator you should consider `a = b = c = 1;`.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is equivalent to :

```
a = ((a == b) == 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

Note, this is phrased this way as it was merged from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517463/testing-equality-among-3-objects). OP asked why `a==b==c` is equivalent to `a==b && b==c` in Objective C (which is a strict superset of C). I asked this answer to be migrated since it cites the specificatio where other answers here do not.

---

#### No, it is not, it's like `(a==b) == c`.

Let's look at a simple counter example to your rule:

```
(0 == 0 == 0);// evaluates to 0
```

However

```
(0 == 0) && (0 == 0) // evaluates to 1
```

The logic is problematic since:

`(0 == 0 == 0)` reads out as `((0 == 0) == 0)` which is similar to `1 == 0` which is false (0).

---

#### For the ambitious student

A little dive on how this is evaluated. Programming languages include *grammar* which specifies how you read a statement in the language. Siance Objective-C does not have an actual specification I'll use the C specificification since objective-c is a strict superset of c.

The standard states that an `equality expression` (6.5.9) is evaluated as the following:

> **Equality Expression:**
>
> relational-expression
>
> equality-expression == relational-expression
>
> equality-expression != relational-expression

Our case is the second one, since in `a == b == c` is read as `equality_expression == relational_expression`  where the first equality expression is `a == b`.

(Now, the actual result number follow quite a way back to a number literal, equality->relational->shift->additive->multiplicative->cast->unary->postfix->primary->constant , but that's not the point)

So the **specification clearly states** that `a==b==c` does *not* evaluate the same way as `a==b && b==c`

It's worth mentioning that [some languages](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) do support expressions in the form `a<b<c` however, C is not one such language.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that results of C comparisons evaluate to `int` and not `BOOL`.

Comment: Xcode evaluates (1 == 1 == 1) as true, but (2 == 1 == 1) as false.

Comment: @DanWesnor Right, because the value for 'truth' is 1 and 'false' is 0. So `1 == 1 == 1` evaluates as `(1 == 1) == 1` which evaluates as `1==1` which evaluates as `1` which is true. On the other hand (`2 == 1 == 1` evaluates as `(2 == 1) == 1)` which is `0 == 1` which evaluates as `0` which is false.

Comment: @DanWesnor Get rid of that "Xcode" word. Xcode does nothing to your code, at best it passes it to the compiler. The **parser** pass in the compiler is what evaluates the expression. And now go read how booleans are represented in C, and you will see why `1 == 1 == 1` is true, so is `1 == 1 == 1 == 1`, etc.

Comment: @DanWesnor it's worth to mention that generally to provide a logical claim like the equivalence of two predicates (expressions) you must show that they produce the same result for _all_ possible inputs and not for a specific assignment (so 1==1==1 does not indicate that `a==b==c` <==> `a==b && b==c` in any way.

Comment: It's fun to see the people who are assuming I'm stupid telling me how C compilers work (hint, I've written one) when the question is on the spec for objective-c.  The objective-c spec is really fluid these days, and the C spec was all over the place when objective-c was forked in the early 80's.  So it seems reasonable that a smart programmer would make sure before assuming everything is the same.

Comment: @DanWesnor No one is calling you stupid or belittling you, this is all a constructive learning experience. I apologize if it sounded like that. Objective-C does not have a spec (at least at the moment) however it _is_ a strict superset of C so everything that applies to C has to apply to it as well.

Comment: @DanWesnor As the question has been merged, please see [this question in meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187796/210016) and let me know what you think.