# Testing equality among 3 objects

Tags: c, equality, comparison-operators

In C `(a == b == c)` seems to give the same result as `(a == b && a == c)`. Is this behavior defined or undefined? Are we guaranteed it will always work that way, or can it change with compiler implementation?

Comment: I'm really surprised that I can't find a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @devnull I think it's a related question but not a duplicate. Although the reasoning and the answer are very similar, the question itself seems sufficiently different.